# Property undefined on production server but works on development

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

We've been implementing a lightbox into our wordpress theme and it works perfectly on our development server which is on the same server as our live site and the build is exactly the same to my knowledge as the build for the development site was just taken from a live site backup, but for some reason on some pages i am getting the following error but on others i'm not as if the JS isn't getting loaded before this JS file but i don't understand why it works perfectly every time on the dev server:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageUrl' of undefined

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

var WHLightbox = {

  settings: {
    overlay: $('.portfolio-tile--overlay'),
    imageCell: $('.cell-image, .portfolio-tile--image')
  },

  data: {
    images: []
  },

  init: function() {
    this.events();
    this.buildImageData();
  },

  events: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.settings.imageCell.on('click tap', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // set up the overlay
      //self._positionOverlay();
      self._openOverlay();
      self._preventScrolling();

      // create the image slide
      self._createImageSlide($(this));


    });
    $('.portfolio-tile--overlay--close').on('click tap', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      self._closeOverlay();
    });
    $('.portfolio-tile--overlay--controls--prev, .portfolio-tile--overlay--controls--next').on('click tap', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.portfolio-tile--overlay--controls--prev').on('click tap', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      self.showPrev();
    });

    $('.portfolio-tile--overlay--controls--next, .portfolio-tile--overlay').on('click tap', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      self.showNext();
    });
  },


  // public functions
  showPrev: function() {
    var index = this.currentImageIndex();
    if(index === 0) {
      index = this.data.images.length;
    }
    this._createImageSlide(false, index-1);
  },
  showNext: function() {
    var index = this.currentImageIndex();
    if(index === this.data.images.length-1) {
      // set to -1 because it adds 1 in the _createImageSlide call
      index = -1;
    }
    this._createImageSlide(false, index+1);
  },

  currentImageIndex: function() {
    if(this.settings.overlay.hasClass('open')) {
      var imageUrl = $('.portfolio-tile--main-image').attr('src');

      for(var i=0; i<this.data.images.length; i++) {
        if(this.data.images[i].imageUrl === imageUrl) {
          return i;
        }
      }

    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },


  // image data
  buildImageData: function() {
    var self = this,
        i = 0;
    this.settings.imageCell.each(function() {
      self.data.images[i] = {
        imageUrl: self._getImagePath($(this))
      }
      i++;
    });
  },


  // slide
  _createImageSlide: function($el, index) {
    var imagePath;
    if(!$el) {
      imagePath = this.data.images[index].imageUrl;
    } else {
      imagePath = this._getImagePath($el);
    }
    this.settings.overlay.find('.portfolio-tile--main-image').attr('src', imagePath);
  },

  _getImagePath: function($el) {
    var imagePath,
        spanEl = $el.find('span.js-cell-image-background'),
        imgEl = $el.find('img.cell-image__image');
    if(spanEl.length) {
      imagePath = spanEl.css('backgroundImage');
      imagePath = imagePath.replace(/url\(["]*/,'').replace(/["]*\)/,'');
    } else if(imgEl.length) {
      imagePath = imgEl.attr('src');
    }

    return imagePath;

  },

  // overlay
  //_positionOverlay: function() {
  //  this.settings.overlay.css({
  //    position the overlay to current scroll position
  //      top: $(window).scrollTop()
  //   });
  //},
  _openOverlay: function() {
    this.settings.overlay.addClass('open');
  },
  _preventScrolling: function() {
    $('html, body').addClass('no-scroll');
  },
  _reInitScrolling: function() {
    $('html, body').removeClass('no-scroll');
  },
  _closeOverlay: function() {
    this.settings.overlay.removeClass('open');
    this._reInitScrolling();
  }
};

WHLightbox.init();

});
```

Comment: at what line of code it give the error?

Comment: The error is happening on line 109:

      imagePath = this.data.images[index].imageUrl;

Comment: ok in this case for sure the element ```this.data.images[index]``` don't exist at the actual index.
you should debug it and see how much element in the array ```this.data.images``` and you have and find why ```index > this.data.images.lenght```

Comment: But i don't understand why it works on the development server perfectly? It is an exact duplicate just on a different URL

Comment: And also it doesn't really make sense that it works on some pages but not all?

Comment: as i said you need to debug the code on the production env to see what is going wrong, i look at the code and it's ok.
i can't do much more other that said why it give error.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to debug it when it works on a lot of pages but not on some, are you able to help with this? If you click on this images on this page you'll see that the imageUrl is loaded for each image but the next and previous buttons gives the JS error http://www.whitehype.co.uk/portfolio/new-communitys-40th-anniversary-newspaper/

Comment: line 78 ```var imageUrl = $('.portfolio-tile--main-image').attr('src');``` have value **http://....** instead of **//....** value in  this.data.images[i].imageUrl so ```if(this.data.images[i].imageUrl === imageUrl) {``` will be always false and the function returns undefined and break all